# typescript this as parameter

Tags: typescript, rxjs5

When I was looking through the rxjs library I stumbled across this function:

```
export function map<T, R>(this: Observable<T>, project: (value: T, index: number) => R, thisArg?: any): Observable<R> {
   if (typeof project !== 'function') {
     throw new TypeError('argument is not a function. Are you looking for `mapTo()`?');
   }
   return this.lift(new MapOperator(project, thisArg));
}
```

source: https://github.com/ReactiveX/rxjs/blob/master/src/operator/map.ts

I'm wondering what really happens when passing an argument named `this`.
Is it just treated like any other parameter or does typescript some special actions when you do this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You cannot directly pass `map` an argument that corresponds to the `this` parameter in the signature. The `this` parameter is used by TypeScript to indicate the type for the context and there is no corresponding argument at runtime.

However, the `map` function can be called using `Function.prototype.call` or `Function.prototype.apply`, and the context can be passed to `call` or `apply`.

For example:

```
import { of } from "rxjs/observable/of";
import { map } from "rxjs/operator/map";

const source = of(1);
const mapped = map.call(source, value => value + 1);
```

In this example, `source` would correspond to `this` in the implementation of `map`, and it would have the type `Observable<number>`.

For more information, see the "`this` parameters" section in the [documentation](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/functions.html).